# Visual studio code C++ : how to display types and address in watches/locals

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, memory-address, watch

I recently switched to Visual Studio Code for C++ programming.

I'm now facing a rather nasty bug (some accesses to freed memory), so I need to look more into detail into what is where in memory.

It would help a lot if when debugging, in the watches/locals, I could display the type and address of variables "automatically". Do you know if there is some solution?

For now, for the addresses, I found I can create a new watch with "&my_variable", but that's quite time consuming if I have to do it for every variable. It would be nicer if it could be always displayed, or at least if there were an option like "left click/display address". If you have a solution working for just objects and/or arrays, it would already be a big step forwards.

PS : platform : linux(xubuntu 20.4); visual code studio v1.66.0 ; debugger : gdb

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_data-inspection